# Fate of Beta Station

Tags: alliance-union

In [C. J. Cherryh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._J._Cherryh)'s [Alliance-Union universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance-Union_universe), what was the fate of Beta Station?

All we know from the [timeline](http://www.cherryh.com/www/chrona5.htm) is that:

> - 2157: Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri] transmission indicates difficulty, is broken up.
> - 2163: ECS7 Santa Maria arrives Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri] from Sol, discovers station deserted, with some dead; it is surmised there was an evacuation to some ship which was built there but which is now lost or enroute.
> - 2163: No word is ever received from the three hundred colonists of Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri], who become legendary among flying dutchman stories.
> - 2164: ECS7 Santa Maria leaves Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri] for Sol after search.
> - 2167: Neutrino message reaches Sol from Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri] about missing colony, setting off wave of xenophobia.
> - 2167: ECS7 Santa Maria arrives Sol from dead Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri]; held for debriefing: event classified.
> - 2183: Glory Station [SS4: Ross 154] is evacuated (which may have been the fate of Beta Station [SS2: Alpha Centauri]) in a long illicit flight to Bryant's Star Station [SS3: 61 Cygni], in ECS11 Mercury.

Some books have characters mentioning Beta Station in conversations, but they are not in full possession of the facts. Is there any reliable information? Apart from the timeline (and especially, more recently than the timeline), is there any word from the author, either in a story or otherwise?

Comment: Is there any reason to doubt the timeline?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I'm looking for information that's not in the timeline: what did happen to Beta Station. (I don't know if there actually is any.)

Comment: My money's on the knnn.

Answer (score 3):

The novels earliest in the Alliance-Union Universe chronology are *Heavy Time* & *Hellburner*, both taking place *ca.* 2300, near the beginning of the Company Wars. With the evacuation of Beta Station taking place *ca.* 2160, there are no contemporaneous witnesses in any of Cherryh’s novels.

Unless someone discovers the derelict, or the time-dilated living ship, in some future novel, or unless Cherryh gives away the story (in which case it’ll likely end up in the timeline), we’ll probably never know what, exactly, happened.

Comment: And before anyone makes the suggestion: Evacuation of Beta Station happened long before the introduction of FTL, so this is _not_ the origin of the lost human ship in the _Foreigner_ universe.

Answer (score 0):

Given that The Compact of the Chanur novels is part of the same Alliance-Union 'verse, I'd agree that the Methane-breather Knnn are the most likely culprits, especially in light of their earlier history of grabbing ships, hauling them off, and gutting them. Given that the events of the Chanur novels are mentioned in historical asides in the Cyteen novels, which are themselves roughly contemporaneous with the Downbelow / Company Wars / Merchanter novels, the mysterious goings-on at old, haunted Beta Station could tie in with the historic bad behavior of the Knnn. Also, the Chanur novels tell us that Human space borders Kif and Knnn space; of the two, the Knnn would be the most likely to dip in, terrorize, carry off the inhabitants of Beta -- behavior they are known for -- and never return. (The Kif, being the opportunistic predators they are, would've found pre-FTL Humanity an irresistible target).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This reads like pure speculation.  Do you have any evidence that the Knnn were involved?  Answers should be based on facts in the books (statements from the author may be acceptable too).  Please read [answer].

Comment: Note that it's also pretty clear that the *Chanur* novels take place _after_ the Company Wars period, with Sol once again starting to build ships.

Answer (score 0):

I have, I think, read everything, and the real answer is "no".  There is, as of yet, no actual direct explanation of it.  There is discussion. *Alliance Rising* had a lot of discussion.

If you are seeking speculation or theory, there are the Kif or Knnn, as Bert Hayling said above, however, I have never seen a map with both Compact space and Alliance Union space.  It is stated that Alliance-Union touches the Knnn and Kif space, but not where or how.  Beta went in the opposite direction as Alpha, so maybe it reached out and touched, but who knows.  As a separate possibility, there is always *Voyager in Night* which was canonically known to be right there to the extent that it made a joke of those sort of jump distances.

Comment: The Kif and Knnn surely don’t act like kith and kin!